# Swift : check if an email has been received with specific attachment type

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I am new on Ios developer.
I was wondering if there is a way to add an observer ( or any other implementation) so that when I receive email with specific attachment type, a notification show up.

the idea is i want my app to listen to evry single incoming email and when an email received with an attachement I got a pop up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no observer notification in IOS that make you able to listen to user mails , but if you are the one who sends the email to the user device , you can add a  push notification capability to trigger something in user app

Comment: yes I am the one who send the email from my app (activityViewController) to another user who has also the same app installed. could you plz just give a hint how to do trigger the push notification on the user device?

Comment: You need a push notification service, such as Amazon SNS, Urban Airship, or one of the various other. Search for "push notification service." Several are free for hobby-level uses.

Comment: push notification in not a sentence explain , it's a feature with a lot of steps (google it and you will find dozens of tutorials ) but after you implement it , send a request to the server from sender user to send a notification to another user with the id of it  (receiver user) , as every user record should have a device token to send the push to him